# Mapping two values in NAnt strings

Tags: nant

I have two nant properties called server and letter that has stings in its value. The goal is to associate the first value of the first string with the first value of the second, and the 2nd value in the first with the 2nd value in the second string. Here is what I have tried.

```
    <property name="server" value="server1;server2"/>
        <property name="letter" value="A;B/>

    <foreach item="String" in="${server}" delim=";" property="server"> 
      <foreach item="String" in="${letter}" delim=";" property="letter">  

       <xmlpoke file="${server}\xml.config" xpath="//@path" value="${letter}" />

     </foreach>
   <foreach>
```

The above results will basically both server 1 and 2 with the letter B value. But really server 1 should have value A and Server 2 have value B. How can this be handled in Nant?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I figured this out, but not too happy with my solution as it have limit my loop to only two values. I don't find a better solution I will update that answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a couple of properties to count how far you are through the loops should help here:

```xml
<property name="server" value="server1;server2" />
<property name="letter" value="A;B" />

<!-- Start at 0 for the server loop -->
<property name="counter.server" value="0" />
<foreach item="String" in="${server}" delim=";" property="server"> 
    <!-- reset the letter counter back to 0 for each server loop -->
    <property name="counter.letter" value="0" />

    <foreach item="String" in="${letter}" delim=";" property="letter">  
        <if test="${counter.server == counter.letter}">
            <!-- perform the task if we're at the same point in both loops -->
            <xmlpoke file="${server}\xml.config" xpath="//@path" value="${letter}" />
        </if>
        <!-- increment letter count -->
        <property name="counter.letter" value="${int::parse(counter.letter)+1}" />
    </foreach>
    <!-- increment server count -->
    <property name="counter.server" value="${int::parse(counter.server)+1}" />
<foreach>
```

This will handle the case where the properties don't have a matching number of items - it will silently ignore them.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks, the counter is the def. the best way to handle this.;) . I created an xml poke target and used the <if test="${not target::has-executed('xmlpoke')}" > in the loop, which worked but was limited. Your solution is the right way. Thanks.